# Implementing a point system on 3d GameObjects in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I want to create a script where you click on a GameObject and collect a point/+1 score, while the GameObject gets deleted. Sounds simple but I just don't know where to start as I am fairly new to coding, I have created the Destroy(gameobject) function but can not seem to implement a point system like how I had in mind as every tutorial on the internet does it with a ui button. Haven't coded anything on this topic yet but I'm hoping to get some explanations on this topic, Thank you for taking your time to read this and have a good day:),

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found that making a PointManager script and AddPointOnClick script, and using it on the GameObject works!
Watch this for more detail: https://youtu.be/YUcvy9PHeXs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).